# How to bind data in TreeListView

Tags: c#, wpf

I use a TreeListView from the following article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/atc_avalon_team/2006/03/01/treelistview-show-hierarchy-data-with-details-in-columns/

I don't know how to set the properties outside the XAML.
Let's say I have a person class with the attributes `lastName`, `firstName`, `gender`, `age` and each person should have its childs as nested levels. How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Model:**

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons}">
    <TreeView.Resources>               
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}" ItemsSource="{Binding Childs}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

**MainWindow:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {


        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        Persons.Add(new Person("Name1"));
        Persons[0].Childs = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        Persons[0].Childs.Add(new Person("Child1"));
        Persons[0].Childs.Add(new Person("Child2"));
        Persons[0].Childs[0].Childs = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        Persons[0].Childs[0].Childs.Add(new Person("Child1 Child2"));



        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; private set; }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am not able to run it. Perhaps there is an error somewhere.

Comment: @Bob let me where and what is the error you are getting.

Comment: Do you have some typos in MainWindow (new List<Persons>)?

Comment: @Bob, Oops.  Sorry for that.  Updated my Answer.